# Blank space before p element

Tags: html, css, fonts

does somebody know why is that empty space just before 15? It's driving me crazy and I can't get rid of it. It's p element ,also the other two under,but the other two don't have this problem..

**Clock displayed which has this problem**

```
.time p{
 font-size: 10em;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-align:center;
}
```

**Other two p elements which have no problem.**

```
.date p{
 font-size: 2em;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }
```

I've tried to fix that with individual paddings but it's not good,because then it's not centered in middle and deviation is still visible from that left side.

My goal is to word **SATURDAY** will be under the first number just like the current date is on opposite side. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: It looks like a fixed-width font. i.e. the `1` is given the same space as the `5`

Comment: Take it easy. Just sit back and wait until 8PM, the problem will be automatically solved.

Answer (score 1):

you could put a 'ghost' text field of 00:00:00 behind your field and turn down the opacity on that so it looks like a real clock. I made an example https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-kirch-hrzby?file=/src/index.js

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K59Oe.png]

Comment: It’s Nice idea! How would you do that? Place background image on div that contains Numbers ? @iamnotsam

Comment: check out my example which I just edited into the original post. Basically it's a couple of CSS tricks.